# Sum value of elements inside of a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I'm doing a sorting of a set of users, I have 4 groupings like so (2 shown):

```
<div id="team1" class="groupWrapper">
  <div id="p1" class="groupItem"><div class="itemHeader"><div class="first">John</div><div class="skill">15</div></div></div>
  <div id="p2" class="groupItem"><div class="itemHeader"><div class="first">Luke</div><div class="skill">5</div></div></div>
  <div id="p3" class="groupItem"><div class="itemHeader"><div class="first">Mary</div><div class="skill">10</div></div></div>
  <div id="p4" class="groupItem"><div class="itemHeader"><div class="first">Bob</div><div class="skill">25</div></div></div>
</div>

<div id="team2" class="groupWrapper">
  <div id="p5" class="groupItem"><div class="itemHeader"><div class="first">Ryn</div><div class="skill">35</div></div></div>
  <div id="p6" class="groupItem"><div class="itemHeader"><div class="first">Kevin</div><div class="skill">15</div></div></div>
  <div id="p7" class="groupItem"><div class="itemHeader"><div class="first">Susie</div><div class="skill">5</div></div></div>
  <div id="p8" class="groupItem"><div class="itemHeader"><div class="first">Jill</div><div class="skill">5</div></div></div>
</div>
...
```

Now what I would like to do is sum up the skill values for each group, on the fly when they are being sorted.

My sorting jQuery script is here:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('div.groupWrapper').Sortable(
            {
                accept: 'groupItem',
                helperclass: 'sortHelper',
                activeclass :   'sortableactive',
                hoverclass :    'sortablehover',
                handle: 'div.itemHeader',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                onChange : function(ser)
                {
                },
                onStart : function()
                {
                    $.iAutoscroller.start(this, document.getElementsByTagName('body'));
                },
                onStop : function()
                {
                    $.iAutoscroller.stop();

                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I would like to be able to 'on drop' of the element, sum up all the totals in every 'team'.  So that whoever sorts the groups always gets the correct skill total per group.

I'm not the greatest user of jQuery yet, but trying to practice more with sortable elements like this.

**EDIT**
I modified my html to include a `<div class='teamskill'></div>` under each `<div id="team#"></div>` element (which contains members).

I wanted to have `teamskill` be updated (the content of it at least).

So I modified the jQuery code to look like so:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('div.groupWrapper').Sortable(
            {
                accept: 'groupItem',
                helperclass: 'sortHelper',
                activeclass :   'sortableactive',
                hoverclass :    'sortablehover',
                handle: 'div.itemHeader',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                onChange : function(ser)
                {
$("div.groupWrapper").each(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(this).find("div.skill").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
  });
  $(this).find(".teamskill").html(total);
});
                },
                onStart : function()
                {
                    $.iAutoscroller.start(this, document.getElementsByTagName('body'));
                },
                onStop : function()
                {
                    $.iAutoscroller.stop();

                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

However, I end up with only the first element `<div class='teamskill'></div>` updating, no other ones (for other teams). Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this would insert a div containing `Total: #` after each group:

```
$(".groupWrapper").each(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(this).find(".skill").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
  });
  $(this).append($("<div></div>").text('Total: ' + total));
});
```

You can adjust the markup, etc...just adjust it based on whatever you want to do with the total.

Comment: How would I add the value to a specific element? Say underneath the specific team1, I have a `<div class="teamskill"></div>` and I wish to put the total there, also keeping in mind the other teams, and also updating those totals at the same time?  I tried adding the following below your .append: `$(this).find(".teamskill").html(total);` but did not work out for all, just the first one.

Comment: @Jakub, that should work, are you replacing `$(this).append($("<div></div>").text('Total: ' + total));` with that?

Comment: yes, I am, I will updated my code above to show your change and where I put everything.

Comment: @Jakub - That shouldn't be happening...can you post the update html including this that it's running on?