# how to sum all value inside div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a element like this

```
   <div id="crt_total_1">10000</div>
   <div id="crt_total_2">20000</div>
   <div id="crt_total_3">30000</div>
   <div id="crt_total_4">40000</div>
```

how to sum all values inside that div to generate results **100000**

Comment: You would be better off assigned the divs a common class name, then you can `getElementsByClassName` or use the class selector in jquery, loop through the collection and sum your values. Either way grab your elements and sum. What really is your question here and what have you tried? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum value of elements inside of a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383772/sum-value-of-elements-inside-of-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interate div to get sum using child and loop

```js
function getSum()
{
var output=0;
$('#cartValContainer').children('div').each(function () {
    output += parseInt(this.innerHTML); // "this" is the current element in the loop
});
return output;
}
var out=getSum();
console.log(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cartValContainer">
  <div id="crt_total_1">10000</div>
   <div id="crt_total_2">20000</div>
   <div id="crt_total_3">30000</div>
   <div id="crt_total_4">40000</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: this will work for all divs that you add inside cartValContainer

Answer (score 4):

Try this:-

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.crt_total').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
});
 alert(sum)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="crt_total">10000</div>
   <div class="crt_total">20000</div>
   <div class="crt_total">30000</div>
   <div class="crt_total">40000</div>
```

Comment: @Derek a broken clock is correct 2 times a day, but nonetheless it is still broken

Comment: Actually jQuery states: "Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid." rtfm: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: @scrappedcola my apologies, I was under the impression OP was using the provided code sample and jquery was doing a search for it in the dom with all like-named types, which is not the case

Comment: @scrappedcola and Derek thanks for upvote and identifying mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can try following single line for getting the sum.

reduce function requires empty array so just check one condition as below.

```
if ($('[id*=crt_total_]').toArray().map(x => parseInt($(x).text())).length > 0) {   
    $('[id*=crt_total_]').toArray().map(x => parseInt($(x).text())).reduce((total, num) => total + num)
}
```

If you are not familiar with lambda expression then you can try following.

```
if ($('[id*=crt_total_]').toArray().map(function(x) { return parseInt($(x).text()) }).length > 0) {
    $('[id*=crt_total_]').toArray().map(function(x) { return parseInt($(x).text()) }).reduce(function(total, num) { return total + num; })
}
```

Comment: You should always prefer an idiomatic approach rather than a 1 liner.

Comment: what if there are other ID with div contains integer value but we don't want that in sum (this will fail to get desired result)

Comment: $('[id*=crt_total_]') this selector will only select those div which have id like "crt_total_". It will not select all divs. You can use class selector also if you like.

Comment: what if I have other id like crt_total_ but I dont want that to sum

Comment: @DineshGhule In that case the it should be like `$('#crt_total_1, #crt_total_2, #crt_total_3, #crt_total_4').toArray().map(x => parseInt($(x).text())).reduce((total, num) => total + num)`  else you need to have  a specific class to each div where total has to be calculated.

Comment: @KiranPaulVJ ok

Comment: Add any fix class in those div which you want to sum. and perform it with class selector. Suppose class is 'crt_total', then you can use $('.crt_total') instead of $('[id*=crt_total_]').

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Attribute Starts With Selector [attribute^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and loop through your value.

```js
var sum = 0;
$('[id^=crt_total_]').each(function(){
  sum = sum + parseInt($(this).text());
});
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="crt_total_1">10000</div>
<div id="crt_total_2">20000</div>
<div id="crt_total_3">30000</div>
<div id="crt_total_4">40000</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time try to show your work (try find your own way and then ask after you got stuck).
Also, elaborate your question better.
But here's what you are looking for.

Assuming you are using JQuery these are steps for you to continue working on your HTML elements.

1. Get your element by JQuery selector.
   `var elem_1 = $('#crt_total_1').text()` and so on for all your elements
2. Parse your value if you need to with `parseFloat(elem_1)`
3. Do your sum function.